# Обработка нажатий пунктов меню, созданных динамически. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Пишу чат. После получения списка комнат нужно создать новые пункты меню(navigationdrawer) в боковом меню. Создать получается, но не знаю, как обработать нажатия таких пунктов. Создаю пункты таким образом:

```
menu.add(R.id.group1,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,JSONrooms.getJSONObject(i).getString("roomName"));
```

[image: пункты меню]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как видно из [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), второй параметр в методе `add` это itemId. Передавайте в него какой-то уникальный идентификатор и по нему в методе `onNavigationItemSelected` вы поймёте какой пункт был выбран.